# Encoding mailto link with body text

Tags: php, encoding, mailto

I'm trying to create a mailto link using PHP. Basically my function gets the body text from database and then creates the html tag like this:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=sample&body=sometexthere">send</a>
```

well, the problem is that my body text may contain non standard characters, like accents and so, so i need to encode the body text before output it; but i don't know how to do it because when my mail client opens (Windows Live Mail) it displays wrong characters for the body.

How can i solve this? what is the right encoding to use unicode text into the body?

many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you're looking for php's `htmlentities()` function.

Comment: It doesn't work, i've encoded the body text using htmlentities but when i click the link my email client opens and there are wrong caracters instead my accented chars...

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement those replacements

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there seems to be an issue with Outlook if there are non-Ascii characters in `sometexthere`.

See this post: [mailto special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987199/mailto-special-characters)