# How to handle special characters while sending email in java?

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, special-characters, jakarta-mail

I am sending a mail using java but when I define special characters in my message body they are not coming properly in the mail. The character I wrote in message body:

```
Hereâ €™s the checklist of what
```

and what I receive is:

```
HereÃ¢ â‚¬â„¢s the checklist of what
```

I'm getting the message body structure in jQuery using this method:

```
messageBody =  $('.messageBody').html();
```

and passing it to servlet using an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/bin/mail',
    data: {    
        emailTo: mailTo, 
        emailFrom: mailFrom,
        attachmentPath: attachmentPath, 
        messageBody: messageBody, 
        emailSubject: emailSubject 
    },
    dataType: 'text', 
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){ 
        $('.thankyou').show();
    }, 
    error: function() { 
        alert("Error");
    } 
})
```

in my servlet

```
String messageBody = (String)request.getParameter("messageBody");

MimeMessage mimemessage = new MimeMessage(session);
mimemessage.setHeader("Content-Encoding","UTF-8");
mimemessage.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, recipients.toArray(new InternetAddress[recipients.size()]));
mimemessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
mimemessage.setReplyTo(new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress(recipient) });
mimemessage.setSubject(subject);
mimemessage.setSentDate(new Date());

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(messageBody, "text/html");
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

mimemessage.setContent(multipart);
```

Comment: can you check with utf-8 i.e. messageBodypart.setConetnt(messageBody,"text/utf-8");

Comment: How does the text look like while debugging? Can you see the special characters displayed correctly in the variables/watch expressions view?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to make a function to accept/replace all those special characters or symbols. But I think you can use `encodeURIComponent(body)` to encode the message body to accept at least some of the special characters.

Found this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034149/passing-special-characters-to-mailto-body-blows-up-javascript) which shows an answer for a similar question.

Hope you can get an idea to solve it.