# How to make special characters compatible with a mailto: link (PHP)?

Tags: php, escaping, special-characters, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to put html into a [mailto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) link (`<a href='mailto:...`)  and using htmlescapechars() but this doesn't seem to be what I need.

```
<a href='mailto:?subject=<?echo $subject_e=htmlspecialchars($subject, ENT_QUOTES)?>&body=<?=$subject_e?>%20via%20https&#58;&#47;&#47;mySite.com&#47;<?=htmlspecialchars($subjectLink, ENT_QUOTES)?>%20'>some text</a>
```

Can anyone explain under what conditions [Example #1 in the htmlspecialchars() part of PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#example-4704) works?

```
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

Running this function on my own server or on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ doesn't seem to convert the special characters.

So it doesn't appear to be a PHP version issue. Including the `encoding` parameter also had no effect. Wtf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987199/mailto-special-characters), I realized instead of `htmlspecialchars()` I just needed `rawurlencode()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Running this function on my own server [...] doesn't seem to convert the special characters.

I bet you’re just *thinking* that because you view the script output as HTML … and what does &lt; display as in HTML? Right, a `<` character …

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at it wrong! The reason you're seeing the HTML tags *IS* because the magic php function is working. Otherwise, it would just render as actual HTML. This is happening because you're likely printing on to an HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

It actually IS working. If you view the source, you will see it is working properly. The HTML is rendering the special chars though

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code of your page you'll see what was generated was exactly what was expected. Loo:

```
     <div class="page-body">
        <div id="code-output" class="code-output">&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;</div>
     </div>
```

The problem is that when you render the page, the html entities are converted to text again. If it's not what you want, you should put the output inside `<pre>` tags.